# Hiding an element through 'Angular js' on click anywhere but its container

Tags: angularjs

I have a div (#div1), which contains a paragraph (#para1) and a button (#button1). Clicking on button adds ng-hide to paragraph and its hidden. But, as paragraph is long when not hidden, I want the click of button to happen, or otherwise (#para1) to be hidden, if user clicks anywhere outside (#div1).

This was eazy by jquery as:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('body:not("#div1")').click(function(){
     $('#button1').trigger('click');
   });
});
```

On trigger of the click (#button1), my paragraph would be hidden, by addClass('hidden') or any other means. I am stuck trying same thing with angular. Can someone help me out doing same thing with angular ?

Comment: Ouch `$('body:not("#div1")')` is not a good idea. You are going to be binding a click function on everything except one `<div>` ... that's going to hurt the DOM performance and memory footprint.

Comment: Does the element printed dynamically? ex by ngRepeat? Please provide some code. Plus you aproach will hurt the dom.

Comment: Yes, the data is being fetched in ('#para1') by ng-Repeat so its height might vary.

Comment: Then your aproach is wrong all the way. You cannot correctly manipulate with Jquery data which was "printed" by ngRepeat. Please provide some code and i'll try later to give you an answer.